# How to display a certain amount of entries from the database in TextViews

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, model-view-controller

**Thank you for your help in advance and I hope my explanation is clear enough.**

I have been working on this app for the REST (Recovery, Education, Support, Training) center for a while and I'm really close to finishing the functionality. This app is built with MVC architecture so there is clear separation of concern. I'd like to have it ready by the time my state opens up.

When I look at the log it shows the data but when it displays the data its only the last entry. How can I get just the last three entries, four entries, and so on to display in the TextView widgets?

**Here is what I have tried:**

FridayActivity calls methods from the database to display the strings in the view which are attached to a layout

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_friday);
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(FridayActivity.this);
        groupsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        TextView fridayGroupNameOne = findViewById(R.id.friday_group_name_one);
        TextView fridayGroupStartTimeOne = findViewById(R.id.friday_group_start_time_one);
        TextView fridayGroupEndTimeOne = findViewById(R.id.friday_group_end_time_one);
        TextView fridayGroupNameTwo = findViewById(R.id.friday_group_name_two);
        TextView fridayGroupStartTimeTwo = findViewById(R.id.friday_group_start_time_two);
        TextView fridayGroupEndTimeTwo = findViewById(R.id.friday_group_end_time_two);
        TextView fridayGroupNameThree = findViewById(R.id.friday_group_name_three);
        TextView fridayGroupStartTimeThree = findViewById(R.id.friday_group_start_time_three);
        TextView fridayGroupEndTimeThree = findViewById(R.id.friday_group_end_time_three);

        db.fridayAddGroup(new Groups(0,"Friday","Daily reflection//Just for today", "9:00 AM", "10:00 AM"));
        db.fridayAddGroup(new Groups(1,"Friday","Step//Sponsorship", "12:00 PM", "1:00 PM"));
        db.fridayAddGroup(new Groups(2,"Friday","Re entry", "2:00 PM", "3:00 PM"));

        /* List all Groups and set to TextViews */
        List<Groups> groupsList = db.getAllFridayGroups();
        for(Groups groups: groupsList) {
            Log.d("friday_activity", "onCreate: "+groups.getGroupName() + " , "
                    +groups.getGroupStartTime() + " , "
                    +groups.getGroupEndTime());
            fridayGroupNameOne.setText(groups.getGroupName());
            fridayGroupEndTimeOne.setText(groups.getGroupStartTime());
            fridayGroupStartTimeOne.setText(groups.getGroupEndTime());
            fridayGroupNameTwo.setText(groups.getGroupName());
            fridayGroupStartTimeTwo.setText(groups.getGroupStartTime());
            fridayGroupEndTimeTwo.setText(groups.getGroupEndTime());
            fridayGroupNameThree.setText(groups.getGroupName());
            fridayGroupStartTimeThree.setText(groups.getGroupStartTime());
            fridayGroupEndTimeThree.setText(groups.getGroupEndTime());
            groupsArrayList.add(groups);
        }
        Log.d("friday_contact_count", "onCreate: " +db.getAllFridayGroups());
    }
```

First method called from the database in the FridayAcvity

```
public void fridayAddGroup(Groups groups) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(DBUtil.KEY_GROUP_NAME,groups.getGroupName());
        values.put(DBUtil.KEY_GROUP_DAY,groups.getGroupDay());
        values.put(DBUtil.KEY_START_TIME,groups.getGroupStartTime());
        values.put(DBUtil.KEY_END_TIME,groups.getGroupEndTime());

        // Insert Row
        db.insert(DBUtil.FRIDAY_TABLE,null,values);
        Log.d("DB handler", "addContact: " + "item added");
        db.close();
    }
```

Second method called from database that iterates through the data with a cursor

```
public List<Groups> getAllFridayGroups() {
        List<Groups> groupsList = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        // Select all contacts from the database table
        String selectAll = "SELECT * FROM " + DBUtil.FRIDAY_TABLE;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectAll,null);

        // loop through the data
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Groups groups = new Groups();
                groups.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                groups.setGroupDay(cursor.getString(1));
                groups.setGroupName(cursor.getString(2));
                groups.setGroupStartTime(cursor.getString(3));
                groups.setGroupEndTime(cursor.getString(4));

                // add contact objects to our list
                groupsList.add(groups);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        return groupsList;
    }
```

the model's class, field variables and constructors

```
public class Groups {
    private int id;
    private String groupDay;
    private String groupName;
    private String groupStartTime;
    private String groupEndTime;

    public Groups(int id, String groupDay, String groupName, String groupStartTime, String groupEndTime) {
        this.id = id;
        this.groupDay = groupDay;
        this.groupName = groupName;
        this.groupStartTime = groupStartTime;
        this.groupEndTime = groupEndTime;
    }

    public Groups() {
    }
```

SQL schema

```
String FRIDAY_GROUP_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + DBUtil.FRIDAY_TABLE + "("
                + DBUtil.KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + DBUtil.KEY_GROUP_DAY + " TEXT,"
                + DBUtil.KEY_GROUP_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + DBUtil.KEY_START_TIME + " TEXT,"
                + DBUtil.KEY_END_TIME + " TEXT);";
```

Table values

```
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "rest_db";
    public static final String FRIDAY_TABLE = "friday_table";
    public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_GROUP_NAME = "group_name";
    public static final String KEY_GROUP_DAY = "group_day";
    public static final String KEY_START_TIME = "start_time";
    public static final String KEY_END_TIME =  "end_time";
```

Here is the logcat output from the Log.d call inside of FridayActivity:

```
2020-05-16 10:42:26.539 3934-3934/com.wesleyruede.testfour D/friday_activity: onCreate: Friday , 12:00 PM , 1:00 PM
2020-05-16 10:42:26.539 3934-3934/com.wesleyruede.testfour D/friday_activity: onCreate: Friday , 12:00 PM , 1:00 PM
2020-05-16 10:42:26.540 3934-3934/com.wesleyruede.testfour D/friday_activity: onCreate: Friday , 12:00 PM , 1:00 PM
2020-05-16 10:42:26.540 3934-3934/com.wesleyruede.testfour D/friday_activity: onCreate: Friday , 12:00 PM , 1:00 PM
2020-05-16 10:42:26.540 3934-3934/com.wesleyruede.testfour D/friday_activity: onCreate: Friday , 12:00 PM , 1:00 PM
2020-05-16 10:42:26.540 3934-3934/com.wesleyruede.testfour D/friday_activity: onCreate: Friday , 12:00 PM , 1:00 PM
2020-05-16 10:42:26.540 3934-3934/com.wesleyruede.testfour D/friday_activity: onCreate: Friday , 12:00 PM , 1:00 PM
2020-05-16 10:42:26.540 3934-3934/com.wesleyruede.testfour D/friday_activity: onCreate: Friday , 12:00 PM , 1:00 PM
2020-05-16 10:42:26.540 3934-3934/com.wesleyruede.testfour D/friday_activity: onCreate: Friday , 12:00 PM , 1:00 PM
2020-05-16 10:42:26.540 3934-3934/com.wesleyruede.testfour D/friday_activity: onCreate: Friday , 9:00 AM , 10:00 AM
2020-05-16 10:42:26.540 3934-3934/com.wesleyruede.testfour D/friday_activity: onCreate: Friday , 12:00 PM , 1:00 PM
2020-05-16 10:42:26.541 3934-3934/com.wesleyruede.testfour D/friday_activity: onCreate: Friday , 2:00 PM , 3:00 PM
2020-05-16 10:42:26.541 3934-3934/com.wesleyruede.testfour D/friday_activity: onCreate: Friday , 9:00 AM , 10:00 AM
2020-05-16 10:42:26.541 3934-3934/com.wesleyruede.testfour D/friday_activity: onCreate: Friday , 12:00 PM , 1:00 PM
2020-05-16 10:42:26.544 3934-3934/com.wesleyruede.testfour D/friday_activity: onCreate: Friday , 2:00 PM , 3:00 PM
2020-05-16 10:42:26.544 3934-3934/com.wesleyruede.testfour D/friday_activity: onCreate: Friday , 9:00 AM , 10:00 AM
2020-05-16 10:42:26.544 3934-3934/com.wesleyruede.testfour D/friday_activity: onCreate: Friday , 12:00 PM , 1:00 PM
2020-05-16 10:42:26.544 3934-3934/com.wesleyruede.testfour D/friday_activity: onCreate: Friday , 2:00 PM , 3:00 PM
```

**Data displays in the view:**
[image: rest_screenshot[2]]

**bonus question:**
If you can tell me why calling `fridayGroupNameOne.setText(groups.getGroupName());` is returning "Friday" instead of "Daily reflection//Just for today" that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Below described rather comments than full answers. But I hope these comments would help you to solve your problems:

1. When you write:

```
for(Groups groups: groupsList) 
   { 
     fridayGroupNameOne.setText(groups.getGroupName());
     ....
   }
```

you all the time overriding text of your TextViews. If you have 3 items in your list - at first loop iteration your code put there group-name from the first item, and at last iteration - group from the list item. That's why your TextViews contains text from only last item in array. Your log shows all three items and that's corresponds with your code. So you should change there your walking-through-the-loop to implement what you want (I don't think it's a very complicated task). But maybe you should read all my comments and to change this part of your code totally.

2. Your code

```
fridayGroupNameOne.setText(groups.getGroupName())
```

is returning "Friday" instead of "Daily reflection//Just for today" I think because in another part of your code:

```
groups.setGroupName(cursor.getString(2));
```

you set index of groupName = 2. But it would be better to get this index explicitly with [getColumnIndex](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor#getColumnIndex(java.lang.String)), since you can't be sure that position of this field in cursor would be 2.

3. In your example you've hardcoded 3 sets of TextView (visible on your screen). If it was in your mind to fix amount of such a data, then OK. But if amount of data you want to show on screen depends on your database data, then you'd better replace set of TextViews with [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview). It would take a lot of time to dive deep there but you can look at this option.

Comment: 1) Oh wow I didn't notice that overriding was the issue. Would it work if I added each element to an array and then indexed the elements from the array such as list[4] == "2:30"? I also feel this is not a complicated task just one that I don't know how to implement. 2) This makes sense. So the issue is that I am not being explicit. Implicit values can be variable. 3) Thank you for recommending a RecyclerView and I'm only uses a limited amount of data from the database. If more than 4 or 5 groups occur in a day I'll likely have to go to a RecyclerView for an efficient scrollable View.

Comment: 1. Yes, something like that. Actually you don't need array, you already get a List from db (from db.getAllFridayGroups()). You can get items with indexes from that data structure.

Comment: I tried to log ```groupsList.get(Integer.parseInt(groups.getGroupName())).toString()``` and it crashed the app. I was thinking to access the groupsList which stores each entry along with the given value.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to get with this code. You get "groupsList" from your db. Let's say its size is 3. To get name of the first group in this list you just can write: groupList.get(0).getGroupName(), of the second - groupList(1).getGroupName() and so on. So to get this it is unnecessary to use loop or to use "groups" variable

Comment: Wooooow! I feel so stupid now. My logic skills aren't always the best so its no wonder I wouldn't see it so straightforward like that. I was thinking to access the groups values per entry in the groupList. Though your efforts I can decrease the complexity of my code by removing the for loop just like you said. Thank you!

Comment: Here is the working implementation as explained by @sergiy
           ```List<Groups> groupsList = db.getAllFridayGroups();
        fridayGroupNameOne.setText(groupsList.get(9).getGroupDay());
        fridayGroupStartTimeOne.setText(groupsList.get(9).getGroupStartTime());
        fridayGroupEndTimeOne.setText(groupsList.get(9).getGroupEndTime());```